# Not getting File from camera

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to do a picture and then open it as an Image in other Activity but I'm not able to do it.
What is working is :

-Open Camera

-Do the photo and save image

Then when I send the path to another Activity is saying that there's nothing on that path.

I'm using a `provider` because otherwise it won't work...

This is my provider in manifest.xml

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>
```

Then I'm taking a picture using this :

```
private void doTakePhotoAction() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        mImageCaptureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(TakePictureAndCropActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "tmp_contact_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

        try {
            intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And then I'm sending this to my other activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("image-path", mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                startActivity(intent);
```

It is returning "" those methods

```
mImagePath = extras.getString("image-path");

            mSaveUri = getImageUri(mImagePath);
            if( extras.getString( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT ) != null ) mSaveUri = getImageUri( extras.getString( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT ) );

            mBitmap = getBitmap(mImagePath);
```

getImageUri is a simple : `return Uri.fromFile(new File(path));` and this is returning me "file:///external/tmp_contact_1541377710472.jpg"

And then I'm getting this :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/tmp_contact_1541377710472.jpg (No such file or directory)

By the way the `provider_paths` contains this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try doing is taking the image as a bitmap, converting it to a ByteArray, passing it in the intent to the next activity, and then converting it back to a bitmap in the second activity. (A bitmap is a type of image file format).

Getting the bitmap:

```
 //This should be in your doTakePhotoAction() method.
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 100);

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
           Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data); 
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Once you get the bitmap from your startActivityForResult, you can do the following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
//convert to ByteArray
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
//Add to intent
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("image",byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
//Convert back to Bitmap.
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Now that you have the bitmap, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Where is this bitemap came from?

Comment: The bitmap comes from the image tkaen on the camera. Refer to the link below to see how to get the bitmap after the picture is taken.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392666/how-can-i-get-bitmap-from-camera-on-android&ved=2ahUKEwiJuPuIi77eAhUIWq0KHXWbDtIQjjgwAHoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw39MxWG13YSJXz7HnlpSzyh